# passive voice with the word ''add''

Tags: passive-voice, indirect-objects

They add a new wing to** the building.

I wanted to know whether  ''the building'' is indirect object or not?

If I change this sentence into passive,

> 1.The building is added with a new wing.
>
> 2.The building is added a new wing.
>
> 3.A new wing is added the building.

Which is correct ?

Comment: A new wing is added to the building, sounds right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "**the building**" is the indirect object here while "**a new wing**" is a direct object.

> Indirect objects are nouns or pronouns that identify to whom or for whom the action of the verb is performed, as well as who is receiving the direct object. Indirect objects are seen infrequently. In order to have an indirect object, there is a direct object. The indirect object typically precedes the direct object and is identified by asking who or what received the direct object. ([**Write.com**](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/grammar/direct-and-indirect-objects/))

The passive is:

- A new wing is added to the building.